# Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7 while deploying GCE back end to server in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I created on GCE (Google Cloud Endpoint) module in an android app which uses a small library I created.
This module is running fine on localhost but when I try to deploy the module Android Studio is giving me the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7:
        com/example/MyJokes.class in F:\nanodegree\BuildItBigger\gce_backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF\lib\jokesdata.jar
Unable to update app: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7:
        com/example/MyJokes.class in F:\nanodegree\BuildItBigger\gce_backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF\lib\jokesdata.jar
Please see the logs [C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg6380880049865072783.log] for further information.
```

[image]
([click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIQ7s.png))

I am using java 8 in android studio

Is there anything I need to change in my project or android studio?

Comment: I don't know how exactly you need to setup your project but you library must be compiled with Java 7 as target (and you can't use Java 8 features in it). How do you make that `jokesdata.jar`?

Comment: jokesdata is created directly from android studio, and same using that in GCE

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine Doesnot support the  java 8  till now(September 2016). so change your java 8(jdk and jre both) to 7 and  change the java fects too. and Problem will get solve.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. From Project settings its showing its using Java 7. How can I change the settings?